# php mailer is not sending mail. may be there is error in code?

Tags: php, email

here is  my code i want to ssend email through php.
this is my code but mail function is not working properly. and it is showing error of : Mailer error could not instantiate mail function.

```
    <?php
                require_once('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
                    $frompage= $_REQUEST['frompage'];   
            if($frompage=="contact"){       
                    $mname= $_REQUEST['mname'];
                    $mmobile= $_REQUEST['mmobile'];
                    $memail= $_REQUEST['memail'];
                    $gemail= str_replace("atsymbol","@",$memail);
                    $mcomment= $_REQUEST['mcomment'];
                    $body = file_get_contents('email-template.html');

                    $body = eregi_replace("<mfrompage>" , $frompage, $body);    
                    $body = eregi_replace("<mname>" , $mname, $body);
                    $body = eregi_replace("<mmobile>" , $mmobile, $body);               
                    $body = eregi_replace("<memail>" , $gemail, $body);     
                    $body = eregi_replace("<mcomment>" , $mcomment, $body);
            }
            if($frompage=="career"){        
                    $mname= $_REQUEST['mname'];
                    $mmobile= $_REQUEST['mmobile'];
                    $memail= $_REQUEST['memail'];
                    $gemail= str_replace("atsymbol","@",$memail);
                    $mcomment= $_REQUEST['mcomment'];
                    $body = file_get_contents('email-template2.html');

                    $body = eregi_replace("<mfrompage>" , $frompage, $body);    
                    $body = eregi_replace("<mname>" , $mname, $body);
                    $body = eregi_replace("<mmobile>" , $mmobile, $body);               
                    $body = eregi_replace("<memail>" , $gemail, $body);     
                    $body = eregi_replace("<mcomment>" , $mcomment, $body);
            }


                $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
                $mail->AddReplyTo($gemail,$mname);
                $mail->SetFrom($gemail,$mname);
                $address = "yogeshkamboj123@gmail.com"; //where email need to be sent
                $mail->AddAddress($address);
            //  $mail->AddCC("shweta.ohlyan@vermillion.net.in", "shweta.ohlyan@vermillion.net.in"); 

                $mail->Subject = "Query from website Vermillion.net.in";
                //$mail->AltBody = "This is for text based email"; // optional
                //$mail->Body=$body;
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);  
            //    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif"); // attachment
            //    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

                if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                echo "Message sent sucessfully!";
                }

            ?>
```

this is my code but mail function is not working properly. and it is showing error of : Mailer error could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: It's been a while since ive seen `ereg` in action. Was that not depreciated in 5.3?

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to make sure that your from address is a valid email account setup on that server.

2.Make sure that you also include smtp class which comes with phpmailer:

```
// for mailing
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");
require  'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check if sendmail is enabled, mostly if your server is provided by another company.

The PHPMailer help docs on [this specific error](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#could-not-instantiate-mail-function) helped to get me on the right path.

What I found is that `php.ini` did not have the `sendmail_path` defined, so I added that with `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i;`